# Regex to validate string pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of strings that represent elements. Some of them are endpoints.

For example:

```
Element1
service/word1/word2/word3
service/word1/word4
Element2
info/word5/word6/word7/word8
info/word5/word6/word7
Element3
Element3 word1
String ABC
```

I need a regex to match only the endpoints **without** knowing the exact length of the endpoints

I'm trying to use following java code with a regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
return p.matcher(str).matches();
```

In order to filter my list as follows:

```
service/word1/word2/word3
service/word1/word4
info/word5/word6/word7/word8
info/word5/word6/word7
```

But I cannot come up with a working regex. Can anyone help?

Comment: So you only want lines that contain a forward slash (`/`), correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The problem is though that I don't know the length

Comment: Do a pattern match for 1 or more any character followed by 1 "/" followed by 1 or more any character. Alternatively, you could make these checks 0 or more depending on if strings like "/word" "word/" or "/word/" should match. You might use 1 or more for "/" if you think stuff like "word//word2" should match. Your first step will most likely be to read a basic introduction to regex matching that uses the tool you are using (Java although you should consider using Linux tools such as grep if it suffices. No need to reinvent the wheel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want 4 matches case of 7 above strings, you can try this

```
\w+(\/\w+)+
```

If you want to match slugs in endpoints (or urls), you may want some more **rules** about your slugs.

Comment: Thanks. with your example and a little bit of "twisting" it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex pattern looks for two groups:

- alpha-numeric ending with a forward slash, I've allowed spaces, hyphens and underscores as they are often included in file and directory names
- word + a number (1 or more digits)
  The second capturing group therefore contains the filename that you want.

```
^([\w\d _-]*\/)*(word\d+)$
```

Please see this tutorial for `java.util.regex.Pattern` and `java.util.regex.Matcher`
[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaregex/javaregex_capturing_groups.htm#:~:text=Capturing%20groups%20are%20a%20way,%22%2C%20and%20%22g%22](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaregex/javaregex_capturing_groups.htm#:%7E:text=Capturing%20groups%20are%20a%20way,%22%2C%20and%20%22g%22).